# will very large http content-length hurt performance especially for mobile environment

Tags: http, tomcat, networking

We have a legacy http client application running on mobile.
It uses http "get" method to download 40M file from a tomcat server, and it does not use chunked encoding.
It is found that using very large content-length would increase the performance in desktop testing, few "get" requests.
Would very large content-length also increase the performance in real world device testing.
Would it be matter that the very large http payload goes through many proxies ?

Comment: 1/ this will not help and 2/ you may be very aware of that, but it is really, _really_ not good. Chunked transfer encoding support is _mandatory_ since (at least) RFC 2616 HTTP/1.1 specification from _1999_, page 26. This app is not merely legacy: it's _vintage_. Good luck supporting it, I sympathize sincerely.

Comment: @jbm: You are mistaken. `Content-Length` is still a thing and nothing *requires* chunked encoding, though it is the preferred method. The only thing required is a way to determine the message length. cf [RFC 7230, section 3.3.3](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.3.3)

Comment: I'm not going to fight about this, yes content-lenght and chunked encoding are a different thing, yes content-lenght is still there and won't go away, yet chunk support _is **mandatory** since HTTP1.1_. From the RFC 7230 you quote yourself, section 4.1. "Chunked Transfer Coding", page 36, "A recipient MUST be able to parse the chunked transfer coding." Was so and did not changed since more than 15 years.

Comment: @jbm Well, we've been talking about slightly different things. I've been referring to the message transfer where nothing enforces the use of chunked encoding while you spoke about client/server capabilities. And in that regard, yes you are right: Conforming recepients must understand it as of HTTP/1.1.